# Show that $\phi:V\rightarrow W$ being a vectorspace homomorphism is injective $\iff$ $S$ linear indep. subs. of $V$ then $\phi(S)$ linear indep. in W

Tags: linear-algebra

I have got Problems to prove "$\Longleftarrow$"

"$\Longrightarrow$"

Let $S$ be linear Independent $V$

Then we Need to show for every finite subset of $S$.

I.e $I\subseteq S: I\text{ finite}\iff I\cong\{1,...,n\},n\in\mathbb{N}$

$\phi(I):=\{\phi(v_1),...,\phi(v_n)\}$ is a linear Independent subset of $W$

$$\iff \sum_{i=0}^{n}\lambda_i\phi(v_i)=0\Longrightarrow \lambda_i= 0,\forall_{i\in\{1,...,n\}} $$

$$\overset{\lambda\phi(v)=\phi(\lambda v)}{\iff}\sum_{i=0}^{n}\phi(\lambda_i v_i)=0\Longrightarrow \lambda_i= 0,\forall_{i\in\{1,...,n\}} $$

$$\overset{\phi(v)+\phi(w)=\phi(v+w)}{\iff}\phi(\sum_{i=0}^{n}\lambda_i v_i)=0\Longrightarrow \lambda_i= 0,\forall_{i\in\{1,...,n\}} $$

$$\overset{f\text{ inj.}\iff \text{ ker}{\phi}=\{0\}}{\iff}\sum_{i=0}^{n}\lambda_i v_i=0\overset{S \text{ is lin. indep.}}{\Longrightarrow} \lambda_i= 0,\forall_{i\in\{1,...,n\}} $$

Comment: For the reverse implication, what is the unique family with one element that is not linearly independent ? ;

Comment: $0$ is never linearly Independent, how do I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\phi(v) = \phi(w)$. Then $\phi(v-w) = 0$, so if you define $S := \{v-w\}$ you have that $\phi(S) = \{0\}$, which is a set of linearly dependent vectors. Then by assumption $S$ is a set of linearly dependent vectors, that means $v-w=0$, i.e. $v = w$. Thus $\phi(v) = \phi(w)$ implies $v=w$, which is injectivity.